# Can you make a javascript function replace itself on the page with custom html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript which will create some sort of widget on a page. I will be giving this snippet to clients so I want them to have to do very little.

The most obvious solution which I have work right now looks something like this:

```
<div id="divContent"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    MakeWidget('divContent');
</script>
```

Make widget basically looks for the divContent div and fill it with my widget's html.

Is there a better way to do this? 
Can you replace a Script Tag with a Div using Javascript in that Script Tag?

I would really like it if I could reduce the code down to only the MakeWidget function and it would replace itself and the script tag with the html the function generates.

Edit - I essentially want to generate HTML exactly where the MakeWidget function is called on the page.

Comment: @JoshStodola Not as strange as it seems, since the goal eliminates the need for unique ids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you replace a Script Tag with a Div using Javascript in that Script Tag?

Yes. When the `<script>` element is reached, assuming it is not a `defer` or `async` script, it will be the last script element in the page so far. So you can say, either inline or in an external script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var scripts= document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var script= scripts[scripts.length-1];
        var div= document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML= 'Whatever content is going to be inserted';
        script.parentNode.insertBefore(div, script);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: TypeError: sscripts is `undefined` line 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have `MakeWidget` defined somewhere, right?  Presumably this is going to be in an external script.  Why not just have the external script source just attach itself to the `divContent` using the `window.onload` method?

This would result in this code on your client's page:

`<script src="http://foo.com/makewidget.js"></script>`

Your `makewidget.js` code could then look like this:
`window.onload = function() { MakeWidget('divContent') }`

There may some issues with other scripts loading and probably some cross-browser compatibility issues but that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: The is that I want to get rid of requiring a specific Div. I want to generate HTML exactly where the javascript was executed.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to have a script element which replaces itself with div.

Your initial code is like this:

```
<div id="divContent"></div>
<script>
MakeWidget('divContent');
</script>
```

You can rewrite it like this (I am using JQuery):

```
<script id="scriptContent">
    $('#scriptContent').after('<div id="divContent"></div>');
    MakeWidget('divContent');
    $('#scriptContent').remove();
</script>
```

I have not tried it though!

Answer (score -1):

I would think it would be possible to do it as follows:

```
<div id="divWidgets">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        MakeWidgets("divWidgets");
    </script>
</div>
```

The end result should be (if I understand your description correctly) that MakeWidgets will replace the contents of the DIV, which, in this case, is the script itself.